# Is there a library with controls like the linq to sql designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a project right now and I need to let the user create some mapping , I love the way the LINQ TO SQL DESIGNER works and i was wondering if somebody knows any control library that has controls similar to those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best one I've found (and use personally) is [LightSpeeds](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed).

You can read more about [Moving from Linq to SQL to Lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/14/moving-from-linq-to-sql-to-lightspeed/) here. Its as easy as drag/dropping a Linq2SQL model onto Lightspeed! No conversion required!! Its also free for models under 8 entities.

*The company is run by the NZ MSFT Regional Director (Jeremy) and another MVP (Daniel-John). The designer I believe was developed from the original work of Ivan Towlson - researching some his earlier work may render you the source code. fyi: The Lightspeed support forum is renowned - you'll see why!*